# Retrieve provider information from IConfiguration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an `Azure Function` I'm trying to retrieve the data from a provider located within `IConfiguration`, the issue is no matter how I approach this I'm unable to extract the data.

Below is how the data is structured in the `IConfiguration`

[image]

This information initially lives inside an `App Configuration` resource in `Azure` and it's loaded in via run time.

I have tried:

```
var azureAppConfigurationData = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAppConfigurationProvider");
var azureAppConfigurationData = _configuration.GetValue<string,string>("AzureAppConfigurationProvider:Data");
var azureAppConfigurationData = _configuration.GetValue<object>("AzureAppConfigurationProvider:Data");
```

However, each result in null

I'm trying to extract the `clientId`, `clientSecret` and the `tenantId` which is then passed into the `Microsoft Graph SDK` to communicate with `Azure B2C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, however, the simplest (without creating a concrete class) would be just to reference the Config Item directly

```
var clientId = _configuration["UserManagement:Settings:B2CClient:ClientId"]
```

<sub>*Assuming, I have typed this correctly*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the spelling and all is correct, however, I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Ignore my comment above, my fault, I pasted your code above the initialisation of _configuration so when I ran it _configuration was null.  It's now working, thanks again.